# FileInputStream and closing

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, fileinputstream, try-with-resources

In my code, wherever a `FileInputStream` is required as an argument, I'm doing this:

```
new obj(new FileInputStream(fileLocation));
```

As I am not assigning the `FileInputStream` to any reference variable, I am not closing it using `close()` method.

Does this result in memory leaks?

Aren't the resources released by the `FileInputStream` in the above approach?

Comment: If the object itself won't close the stream, then yes you've got a resource leak.

Comment: Note: a **resource** leak, not a memory leak.

Comment: The reason im asking is this question is : With the implementation i mentioned above , i received an exception FileNotFound(too many open files) after a couple of runs.
Thought of knowing whether the reason for this issue is not closing the streams.

Answer (score 0):

if there are no references to your input stream, it will be garbage collected and the stream will be automatically closed - see `FileInputStream.finalize()` method. However, it is not a good programming practice because you do not know when garbage collection will happen. So this could result in memory leak.

correct and much safer approach is to use try with resources block, or in older java versions try-catch-finally, where you close the stream in finally block - I personally like IOUtils from Apache Commons, you do not have to care about `IOException` thrown by `close()` method

Comment: Finalization does not happen as soon as the object is garbage collected. The garbage collector sees the object needs finalization and queues it for finalization. The finalization itself may never happen even though garbage collection comes and goes. Thus it's never good practice to rely on `finalize`, and thus this situation *is* considered a resource leak.

Answer (score -1):

The general answer here is no. If all you know about the object is that it is an object then you cannot assume it will close the `FileInputStream` on it's own and you should make sure to handle that yourself; try-with-resources in Java7 make this trivial.

```
try(FileInputStream fileStream =new FileInputStream(fileLocation);){
   Obj obj = new Obj(new obj(fileStream));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    //handle exception
}
```

---

On the other hand, If you know that the object implements the `AutoClosable` interface you can assume that the `FileInputStream` will be closed when the other object is closed.

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html):

> Closes this resource, relinquishing **any underlying resources**. This
>   method is invoked automatically on objects managed by the
>   try-with-resources statement.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>